# Add elements to struct by define

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, struct, c-preprocessor

I have a problem. I'm trying to add struct elements by previously defined constant.
This is sample code (OpenGL+WinAPI)

```
#define ENGINE_STRUCT \
    HGLRC       RenderingContext;\
    HDC         DeviceContext;
```

And then:

```
typedef struct SWINDOW {

    ENGINE_STRUCT

    HWND        Handle;
    HINSTANCE   Instance;
    CHAR*       ClassName;
    BOOL        Fullscreen;
    BOOL        Active;
    MSG         Message;
} WINDOW;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, a macro is a simple textual substitution

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

> The preprocessor examines the code before actual compilation of code
>   begins and resolves all these directives before any code is actually
>   generated by regular statements.

Comment: Oh... thanks... :) It didn't work, but now somehow it works :D Probably an error was in another place, but it doesn't change the fact, that the error was in struct and pointed to this defined constant... strange, but thanks anyway :)